# display: table-cell height issue

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a horizontal navigation which displays like a table.

The markup is as follows:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">multi line link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">any other link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

display: table-cell seems to calculate the extra-space and add padding to fill the blank.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F6DKx/

I need it to increase the height instead to fill the extra space, so the anchor element inside can be just as high to absolutely position a child at it's bottom.

Here's the css:

```
nav { display: table; }
ul { display: table-row; }
li { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
a { position: relative; height: 100%; }
a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 50%;
    width: 5px; height: 5px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A good idea is to add your code in fiddle - it will help you have more answers.

Comment: Please supply a working [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to illustrate and reproduce your exact problem. The code you have now doesn't do much.